# Selecting a button/label in selenium web driver to display more text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

So in the webpage I am trying to write some selenium for, there is a label that causes more text to be displayed.  I am trying to figure out how to have selenium select the label and then have the rest of the text displayed.

The button/label I am trying to get it to select is `<label class="btn_expand" for="kpanel">Show Full Display</label>`

When I tried using select I got an error "Element should have been select, but
instead was label".  This was the code I tried -

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class=' btn_expand']")));
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText("Show Full Display");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You trying create DropDown list from label tag. Possibly you wrongly understand what is Select. Please, write more clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to make it so Selenium will select a button which has the text "Show Full Display".  When it selects this button, things that were previously hidden are shown.   

I have no attachments to Select, so if you have a possible solution that doesnt involve selects, that is totally fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) to learn what a SELECT HTML tag is. You don't want a SELECT tag, you want the LABEL tag.

Your XPath is not efficient... it contains more than is actually needed to find that element. XPath, in general, is error prone, fragile, and slow. I prefer CSS Selectors. Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='kpanel']")).click();
```

Comment: Ah ok.  Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2):

I actually fixed this problem by using:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(//label[text() = 'Show Full Display']/@for)")).click();
```